# Sorting a Camera Mesh

Tags: python, python-3.x

Aim: To find out how many camera's can communicate and therefore in the same mesh. The tuples are camera coordinates and r is max distance they can be apart. n= amount of camera's

My code takes a list in this case numl and arranges it into pairs of coordinates based on whether or not the value of p <= r^2. Resulting in a list like lis = [ [(3,4),(5,6)] ,[(2,4),(5,9)], [(1,4),(5,6)] ]
I attempt to compare the values in the area i highlighted as my prob area and join any lists which had one tuple similar. In the example above for instance if any of the elements in lis[0] match any of the elements in the others then I would merge those to minus the duplicate and end up with [(3,4),(1,4),(5,6)]  ,[(2,4),(5,9)]]

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

```
 def smesh():
   fin = []
   i = 0 
   numl= [9,8,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2]
   r = numl.pop(0)
   r = r**11
   n = numl.pop(0)
   flis = numl[::2]
   numl.pop(0)
   slis = numl[::2]
   newl = list((zip(flis,slis)))
   for x,y in itertools.combinations(newl,2):
     p = (((x[0]-y[0])**2)+ ((x[1]-y[1])**2))
   if p<=r:
       fin.append([x,y])
   <---below here is my prob area--->
   for x,y in itertools.combinations(fin,2):
     if x[0] in y:
      fin.append(x+y)
     elif x[1] in y:
       fin.append(x+y)
   print(fin)
```